# TypeScript console log print different value from same object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using Angular version 8 with RJXS library. I print the object variable in order to have some logs but I have seen a strange behaviour:

```
Object { carName: "Sorbonne", age: "20", type: "C1" }
​
carName: "BB"
​
age: "23"
​
type: "PROPA"
​
<prototype>: Object
```

[or in image format is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh7NO.png)

This is the code:

```
 this.carService.subscriptionUpdatingCarObservable.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((car: Car)   => {
        console.log(car)
     [...]
    });
```

I'm not able to understand why in the same console the values can change. Have you an idea for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happends most probably because you are mutating your car object somewhere. chrome console is pretty smart, and it doesn't convert your object to string, when you console.log it. it rather puts a reference to that object, and, you can check actual values of that object when you expand it